# API to export Office 365 Outlook Mail in PST format?

Tags: outlook, ms-office, office365, office365api, office365-restapi

Is there any sort of API to export the Office 365 Outlook Mail in PST format?

I am able to export the mail in PST format from **Office 365 Exchange Admin Center** using in-place eDiscovery mechanism.

But want to export the mail in PST format through REST API and not from admin section.

Thanks in advance,

Ramesh

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what Eric mentioned, you can create a PST file if Outlook is already installed (you won't need a profile pointing to the source Exchange mailbox - just the MAPI system to be able to create PST files) using [Extended MAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815424.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (C++ or Delphi) or Redemption (any language - I am its author) - call [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`LogonPstStore` to create a temporary profile with a PST file, you can then create folders and items in the store. EML files can be imported using [RDOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm).`Import(..., olRfc822)`.

Also keep in mind that EML format does not preserve all MAPI specific properties (unless you export in the TNEF format). I know this question is for the REST API, but in case of EWS, you can use the [ExportItems EWS operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/exportitems-operation) - unlike EML, Fast Transfer Stream is similar to TNEF and MSG formats and preserves all MAPI properties. The FTS format is not officially documented (but not hard to hack) and [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) will let you import files in the FTS format using [RDOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm)`.Import(..., olFTS)`.

Comment: I think that Extended MAPI or Redemption won't be able to create PST file from Office 365 Mail directly.

Comment: I just outlines above how that can be done. Which part are you having doubts about?

Comment: So, you are saying that we can create PST file from the email data obtained through Graph API using Redemption/Extended MAPI but not directly export office 365 mailbox to PST file.

Comment: Yes, as long as the MAPI system is installed you can create a PST file.

Answer (score 3):

The .pst file format is only relevant with the Outlook client, so Outlook Online and the REST API has no integration with it whatsoever.

However, you can get all the email data through the Graph/REST API and create the .pst file yourself. See the .pst file format specs here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff385210(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Thanks. If not REST API then is there any sort of script like cmdlet or powershell script that can export the Office 365 Outlook Mail to PST file?